# Update like insert

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to perform *update* like *insert*?

```
UPDATE `table` SET `value` ('N','N','N','N','Y','Y','Y','N', 'N') WHERE `my_id` = '1'
```

The problem is that the number of values ​​to be inserted i dont now. It can be a 5 or 10.
[image]

Comment: what you want to do? you can not change in to my sql libraries function.

Comment: Update multiple records? or multiple columns of one record?

Comment: @xdazz update multiple records with certain id with values from array (arrays length matches affected rows number)

Comment: It looks to be a bad design and not a missing function.

Comment: @user1564141 Where does the array values come from?

Comment: @xdazz i save it before any changes.

Comment: You want to update the first N rows where my_id=1 and set `value` of each row with the values in the array? If so, how do you later use the data in this table? If you are just update the first N, how is each row associated with anything? How are the Y, N values set/gathered?

Answer (score 8):

replace is just like insert, it just checks if there is duplicate key and if it is it deletes the row, and inserts the new one, otherwise it just inserts

you can do this if there is for example unique index of (Name,Type) and if you type the following command

```
REPLACE INTO table1 (Name,Type,InitialValue,FinalValue) VALUES ('A',3,50,90 )
```

and there already exists a row with Name = 'A' and Type = 3 it will be replaced

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name_type ON table1(Name,Type)
```

EDIT: a quick note - REPLACE always DELETES and then INSERTs, so it is never a very good idea to use it in heavy load because it needs exclusive lock when it deletes, and then when it inserts

some of the database engines have

INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the `column-name`.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `Col1`='y',`Col2`='n' ... WHERE `ID`='1'
```

Or want to update one or more columns/rows:

```
UPDATE `table` Set Col1='Y' WHERE `ID` IN ('1','11','13')
```

Comment: Seems the op doesn't mean this.

Comment: I don't think its columns being updating, but different rows where my_id is 1 with different values for each row

Comment: Yeah! but I'm not sure what **OP** is really trying to tell us.

Comment: I don't think anyone is sure :)

Comment: @AVD i just need to update all rows `bool` where `my_id` to values from array.

Comment: @AVD is there a possibility to perform something like UPDATE `table` Set Col1='Y' WHERE `ID` IN ('1','11','13') AND Set Col1='N' WHERE `ID` IN ('5','10','15') ?

Comment: You've to prepare/execute two statements - `UPDATE Tab Set Col1='A' Where ID in (1,2,3);UPDATE Tab Set Col1='B' Where ID Not in (1,2,3)`